# How to import cast_receiver.js from Cast SDK in webpack project?

Tags: webpack, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm trying to use [cast_receiver.js](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/cast/client-side/receiver) in my `webpack v5` setup. Basically, I want to import the `Google Cast` classes like you would with any other import. Something like:

```js
import cast from 'cast';
// or...
import cast from '//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js';
```

And then the resulting `index.html` should reference that exact url:

```html
<head>
  <script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
</head>
```

Reading the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), it seems this should be possible using `externals`. However, I'm not able to get this to work. I keep getting this error:

> Cannot find module 'cast' or its corresponding type declarations.

Here is my **webpack.config.ts**:

```
externalsType: 'script',
  externals: {
    cast: [
      '//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js'
    ]
  },
```

**Q: how can I import `cast_receiver.js` in my `webpack` configuration?**